# Oracle APEX looping through CheckBox Group elements

Tags: checkbox, plsql, oracle-apex, apex, oracle19c

I need to make the function of inserting data into several tables at once in the ORACLE APEX App Builder. Interactive report displays information from the View collected from the tables "Book", "Autors_list", "Autor", where "Autors_list" is needed to reveal the many-to-many relationship between the author and the book.

So, on an automatically created form, when I click on the CREATE button, using a dynamic event, I try to add data to the "Book" and "Autors_list" tables.

The data I'm trying to add:

***P15_ID_BOOK*** - book id - add to "Book" and to "Autors_list"

***P15_BOOK_NAME*** - book name - add to "Book"

***P15_AUTORS*** - authors - are represented using the *Checkbox Group* - I need to go through each of its elements and for each element add an entry to the "Autors_list" in the form (P15_BOOK_NAME, author id from P15_AUTORS)

***P15_PUBLICATION_DATE*** - publication date - add to "Book"

***P15_PRICE*** - book's price - add to "Book"

The CheckBox Group is set using the following List of Values

`

```
select "id_autor", (CONCAT(CONCAT(autor."Name", ' '),autor."Surname")) as "Autors" from "Autor" autor;
```

`

I wrote the following PL/SQL code to add the above values to the tables:

```
begin
insert into "Book"
("Name", "Publication_date", "Price")
values
(:P15_BOOK_NAME, :P15_PUBLICATION_DATE, :P15_PRICE);

FOR i IN (select * from table(apex_string.split(:P15_AUTORS, ',')))
LOOP
 insert into "Autors_list"
 values (:P15_ID_BOOK, i);
END LOOP;
end ;
```

However, it gives me an error

> ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Please tell me how to cycle through the elements of the Checkbox Group correctly and get the values from there

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is not how you would do this in apex. You say *So, on an automatically created form, when I click on the CREATE button, using a dynamic event, I try to add data to the "Book" and "Autors_list" tables.*

If the form is automatically created, then a page process will be created to handle the insert into "book" for you. There is no need to create a dynamic action (not "dynamic event") to do this. Everything will be done when the page is submitted. That is the "normal" flow in apex: a page is rendered, the user enters data, and then the page is submitted (and all processing is done). Dynamic actions are used to manupilate the dom, perform ajax callbacks, etc - all the things that do not require a page submit.

The only think that is left to be done is to create an additional page process  to insert the child records in the "Authors_list" table. That page process needs to happen after the form process since the value for :P15_ID_BOOK will be generated on insert of the record in to books.

The code of your page process will be something like what you already have

```
FOR i IN (select * from table(apex_string.split(:P15_AUTORS, ',')))
LOOP
 insert into "Autors_list"
 values (:P15_ID_BOOK, i);
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Thanks fo answer. I understand about the page process now, but this automatically created form was created for the View that combines tables "Book", "Autors_list" and "Autor". So, when I submit form I get an error that I cannot add virtual column (or something like that). How can I insert values first in "Book" and then in "Autors_list"?

Comment: Not sure that is possible - typically a form creates or updates a single record. From what you described above, there will be multiple records for a single book. 
Here is what I would do. Create a form on the table "Book" only. Then add a page item for anything attributes that are not in book manually like I describe in my answer.